# JavaScript module explained

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between this way:

```
var MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.Helper = function()
{
     var _getValue = function()
     {
         var value = 5;

         return value;
     };


    return 
    {
         getValue: _getValue
    };
}();
```

and this way:

```
var MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.Helper = function()
{
    function _getValue()
    {
       var value = 5;

       return value;
    };

    var publicMethod = 
    {
        getValue: function() { _getValue(); }
    };

    return publicMethod;    
};
```

Comment: The second `getValue` won't return anything.

Comment: Is that proper way to use module pattern in JavaScript? I guess noo

Comment: That second version is just plain wrong ..

Comment: Can the second part be instantiated something like: MyNamespace.SomethingElse = new MyNamespace.Helper(); And if yes what will be the benefit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two pretty significant differences:

1. The first version doesn't return an object, so `MyNamespace.Helper` will be `undefined`. Trying to use `getValue` on it will fail. This is thanks to Automatic Semicolon Insertion adding a `;` after the `return`. Don't put line breaks after `return` and what it returns.
2. Assuming you fix that, then calling `MyNamespace.Helper.getValue` on the first one will give you the value `5`, whereas calling it on the second one will give you `undefined`, because your anonymous wrapper around `_getValue` doesn't return anything.